# Black Screen Ubuntu 14.04 – a possible cause

Tags: 14.04

**Black Screen Ubuntu 14.04 – a possible cause**

LATER EDIT:
After posting here all the informations that I have gathered these few days, I have made also two movies about this Black Screen issue, and the temperature sensor, and I uploaded them on Youtube.

Here they are:

The first video: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9hxdFxxTozg

The second video: 
https://youtu.be/Esqm4tlpLJk

Help that those ones make the things a little bit more clear for you.

---

Hello everyone. I think I have found a cause for the famous BLACK SCREEN on Ubuntu 14.04, and I hope to find a solution for this problem here.

I am struggling with a black screen issue on Ubuntu 14.04. 
My desktop has multiple operating systems running, each one installed on a different HDD.
My desktop runs Ubuntu 14.04, Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7.

Both Ubuntu 12.04  and Windows 7 run with no problem, but Ubuntu 14.04 presents from time to time a black screen. If sound is running in the time of event, the sound continues to run, only the screen image is missing.

On Ubuntu 14.04 (and only on that OS) the black screen can appear a minute after the system is on and going, or after an hour, or after two hours, or the system can run a day or two with no problems at all! Only to present that black screen again three days later. And that is more confusing for me.

I have google searched and entered in numerous threads about this BLACK SCREEN issue (this is why I sayd  the *famous* BLACK SCREEN on Ubuntu 14.04), but with no success. 
The graphic card is an old ASUS EAH 3870X2 (AMD ATI) with two graphic processors.
It has no more support for drivers on Linux from the manufacturer (and I will never ever again buy AMD ATI products).

However, somewhere on the big www somebody said something about the BLACK SCREEN issue on a laptop that he had just purchased, showing the black screen problem. He tested the GPU temperature with the command sensors in Terminal. The temperatures presented there were way too high. That guy finally returned the laptop in the 30 days time he had for no matter what return. And that was all.

Following that path I tested my Ubuntu 14.04 with the sensors command in Terminal on Ubuntu 14.04, and to my stupefaction the result shown was a + 115 C for one GPU processor, and a + 91 C for the second GPU processor!!!!!!!!!!!

And that with almost no video activity at all, only the OS running a fresh boot and the Terminal on (of course).

I have rebooted on Ubuntu 12.04 to seek for temperature results. Here I could place in terminal the command:

aticonfig --  odgt

and the result was: 
Default Adapter ATI Radeon HD 3870 X2
Sensor 0: Temperature 56 C.

Then I rebooted on Windows 7, and the results obtained from HWINFO64 were somewhere on the same range, 53 C on one GPU, and 52 C on the second GPU.

Is it possible that Ubuntu 14.04 operating system is killing the graphic card output if the temperature is too high?

If it does, then why the GPU temperature on 14.04 is listed so high?

My graphic card cannot reach + 115 C on a fresh boot with no activity at all!!!! And it does not, because on Ubuntu 12.04 and w7 the temperature shows temperatures somewhere around 56 C.

So, what is happeninng on Ubuntu 14.04 with GPU Temperature sensors?

What is the solution for this problem? Possiby this problem affects many others who are struggling with this BLACK SCREEN issue. Many of them have this problem even from trying to boot a live Ubuntu  DVD that leads them only to a black screen. Even the installation of this OS is compromised.

Later Edit:

Today I have tried a few more tests regarding GPU temperatures on different operating systems on my  desktop, and the black screen phenomen.

First, I booted on Windows 7 and opened HWiNFO64.
I looked at the temperatures of the GPU (fresh boot, no hard video load, only HWiNFO64 **sensors** running):
GPU Thermal Diode 51 C
GPU Thermal Diode 49 C

Then I have **completely stopped one of the two coolig fans** of the graphic card (the graphic card has two cooling fans, it is a big graphic card).

I kept the cooler on hold for two minutes. The time was registered with a cronometer on my telephone.

After two minutes the video on my monitor was still on and going strong. No problems at all.
The temperatures of the GPU after two minutes (one cooling fan blocked by me, only HWiNFO64 sensors running):
GPU Thermal Diode 62 C
GPU Thermal Diode 51 C

I released the fan and let the cooler to run a few minutes to cool again the graphic card.

After that **I have stopped both cooling fans** of the graphic card.
After two minutes the video on my monitor was still on and going strong. No problems at all.
The temperatures of the GPU after two minutes (both cooling fans blocked by me, only HWiNFO64 sensors running):
GPU Thermal Diode 73 C
GPU Thermal Diode 68 C

So, on W7 the system was still going on after two minutes, **with both cooling fans stopped.**

Next I did the same tests on Ubuntu 12.04 and on Ubuntu 14.04. Here, due the fact that the temperature was not displayed on continuosly, but the command must be entered on Terminal, I asked my wife to help me. She was quicly paste the command (aticonfig --  odgt on 12.04, respectively sensors on 14.04, copied previously) and then hitting Return, to obtain the results, while I was keeping the fans blocked and watching the time on the stopwatch.

On **Ubuntu 12.04** the results were:
 **With one of the two GPUs coolig fans stopped:**
The system presented a **black screen** after 1 minute and 12 seconds.
The last temperature displayed on terminal was 55 C.

**With both GPUs coolig fans stopped:**
The system presented a **black screen** after 48 seconds.
The last temperature displayed on terminal was 58 C.

On **Ubuntu 14.04** the results were:

The temperatures with the system 14.04 fresh boot

radeon-pci-0300 
Adapter: PCI adapter 
temp1:       +112.0°C

radeon-pci-0400 
Adapter: PCI adapter 
temp1:        +95.0°C

**With one of the two GPUs coolig fans stopped**:
The system presented a **black screen after 7 seconds**.

The last temperatures displayed on terminal were
radeon-pci-0300 
Adapter: PCI adapter 
temp1:       +122.0°C

radeon-pci-0400 
Adapter: PCI adapter 
temp1:        +97.0°C

**With both GPUs coolig fans stopped:**
The system presented a **black screen after 4 seconds**.
The last temperature displayed on terminal were somewhere the same of the ones above (122 C).

Then I have completed a cicle by running the tests again on w7. That in order to see if the computer has been getting or not warmer on the use, and leading to worst results on Ubuntu 14.04.

But again, the computer was still going on on W7 after two minutes of cooling fans blocked. The result were

the temperatures of the GPU after two minutes (one cooling fan blocked by me, no hard video load):
GPU Thermal Diode 55 C
GPU Thermal Diode 52 C

the temperatures of the GPU after two minutes (both cooling fans blocked by me, no hard video load):
GPU Thermal Diode 71 C
GPU Thermal Diode 73 C

Conclusion:

1. On windows 7 the system was still showing video content even after two minutes of both cooling fans blocked.
2. On Ubuntu 12.04 the system displayed a black screen after 1 minute and 12 seconds with one cooling fan blocked, and after 48 seconds with both cooling fans blocked.
3. On Ubuntu 14.04 the system displayed a black screen after 7 seconds with one cooling fan blocked, and after 4 seconds with both cooling fans blocked

Ubuntu 14.04 performs the worst of the three OSs.

I am sure that my graphic card cooling system is good. 
That is due to the fact that, even it is a 6 years old graphic card, I have recently (two months ago) cleaned it up. 
I have completely dismounted it, changed the thermal paste, changed the thermal pads, cleaned it up. 
It runs with no problems on w7. 
I cannot even block the video display on w7, even with both coolers completely stopped.

Something is about the way that Ubuntu s  Temperature sensors read the values, and about how Ubuntu  takes the decision to kill the video output.
Especially on Ubuntu 14.04 this is a problem who affects many people.

For the moment I have added to my system two cooling fans to blow over the graphic card. One 100x100 mm fan, and a smaller one.

Still I hope to find a better solution for this problem.

Best regards.

Comment: I can see now that the if we apply x2 on the 56 C reported by Ubuntu 12.04, then 56 x 2 = 112 C. Near the 115 C reported by Ubuntu 14.04. Does Ubuntu 14.04 somewhat doubles the results of the real temperature? And why? The fact that the GPU have two processors mislead the sensors result?

Comment: No, the result from 12.04 doesn't need to be doubled.

Comment: Could it be possible that the OS is confusing °F with °C? For instance, 50°C equals 122°F. If the sensor sent an indication of 122°F and the OS interpreted that as 122°C then there would be a problem, as the OS would believe that the GPU had reached a temperature of 252°F!

Answer (score 1):

While I was looking for more informations about temperature sensors on Ubuntu, I found a page about lm-sensors on Ubuntu here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SensorInstallHowto

They say in that post that:

***As you can see, some sensors are obviously incorrect (e.g. AUX Temp and Case/Aux Fan); this tends to be the case with at least some of the sensors on most motherboards.***

The AUX Temp in the example that they mentioned was:

***AUX Temp:   +124.5°C  (high = +80.0°C, hyst = +75.0°C)  ALARM  sensor = thermistor***

So, for Ubuntu OSs:

- ***sensors can detect obviously incorrect temperatures***, as shown on that article about lm-sensors.
- ***sensors can detect obviously incorrect GPU temperatures***, as shown in my post above with a wrong + 115 C GPU temperature detected by 14.04 for my GPU.
- ***Ubuntu can take the decision to kill the video output***, as demonstrated by me by blocking one or both graphic card cooling fans, leading to a black screen monitor.

Yes, I am pretty sure that I have found one of the possible causes for the black screen Ubuntu!

Comment: It would be good if people who are facing now this black screen issue when trying to install Ubuntu on their laptops or desktops, they would cooperate.

It would be interesting that those people would try to cool their systems heavily before and during  the run of the Ubuntu's installation DVD.

If by cooling their system heavily when running of Ubuntu's live DVD, they manage to get to the Ubuntu desktop, that could  mean that it is possible that they are facing a sensors incorrect GPU temperatures detection.

Answer (score 1):

Now, armed with these informations that I gathered the last two or three days, I can see better the things that had happened with my computer on the last two months.

As I have told you previously, about two months ago I have serviced my 6 years old ASUS EAH 3870X2 Graphic Card, who was waiting that maintenance stored somewhere in a box in my house. My destop had another Graphic Card installed at that time. I have completely dismounted the ASUS EAH 3870X2, changed the thermal paste, changed the thermal pads, I cleaned everything up. After that, I have installed the  ASUS EAH 3870X2 Graphic Card on my desktop.

Due to the fact that the motherboard (an ASUS P5E3 Premium) has two slots for Graphic Cards, I have decided to install the  ASUS EAH 3870X2 Graphic Card on the slot the closest to the bottom of the dektop case. 
I was thinking that the air close to the bottom of the case is the cool air, and the warm air is located higher inside the case. 
But I can see now that that was a bad idea. 
That because the space left between the graphic cards cooling fans, and the bottom of the desktop was very small, maybe 3 centimeters (a little more than one inch). 
I think that the warm air blown out by the GPU coolers was sucked back again by the same vents, and leading to a fast temperature rising. 
At least high temperatures for the 14.04 sensors, because for 12.04 and w7 were running with no problems.

What happened was that after this Graphic Card installation (in this position) I have been able to run Ubuntu 12.04 and windows 7 with no problems at all.

When I was trying to run Ubuntu 14.04 the system booted, sometimes leading me to a black screen, and sometimes I get as fas as to to be able to see the desktop for maybe 20 seconds, and after that I was getting the black screen.
I have had the Graphic Card mounted in this position for about 6 weeks. In those 6 weeks I have tried to solve this situation on Ubuntu 14.04.

I have been able to enter in the OS with **nomodeset**, no black screen at all when running on **nomodeset**, but due to the fact that AMD ATI has stopped the support for this Graphic Card for 14.04, and I have had no drivers available to install, I was unable to work around and find a permanent solution.

I was even thinking to reinstall 14.04 to get back my OS. But running the installation DVD took me to the famous black screen.

I have even thought to install something else, so I tried to install Linux Mint, or Ubuntu Mate, but the installation DVD's all send me only to look at a black screen.

After that, I  thought what about this situation is due to the fact that the Graphic Card is mounted in the wrong motherboard slot? 
It is said that, if you have only one memory RAM stick available, it is best to insert it on the motherboard's RAM slot the closest to the processor.
What if the same thing was also true for the Graphic Card?

So I took the Graphic Card, and mounted it on the other slot, the one closest to the processor. 
That gave some more space below the Graphic Card, between the cooling fans and the bottom of the case. Now the free space is around 7,5 cm (about 3 inches).

After that move, a miracle happened: my Ubuntu 14.04 was running again!!!!! 
It was not perfect, as he had from time the the black screen issue, but it worked a lot better than before! 
It run without the need of **nomodeset**. 
It's true that I had the black screen issue from time to time, but at least it worked fine 98% of the time!

The fact that I still have the black screen issue every now and then was the reason that I have continued to search for possible causes. And that leaded me to make these tests and to post these observations here.

Hope that these observations help, and hope that someone will find solutions for the video black screen issues on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've hit on a good solution.  I had a similar thing happen with Ubuntu 14.04, but on an Nvidia GeForce card (a 12 old one, but decent, even today).  This card continues to show high temps due to wear and tear from old age, but in Ubuntu it was worse.  Nice job helping everyone out with, what I think is, the most stumper of a question out there.